# How can I find the next related (but slightly different) transaction in an Oracle table, possibly using LEAD?

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I have a transaction table with a large number of events with a number of event types.  I'm looking to do some analysis on two related event types: transit-send and transit-receive.  A sample of the table looks something like this:

```
 ItemID | EventType | TransactionDate
--------|-----------|-----------------
 11111  | send      | 2013-07-02
 22222  | receive   | 2013-07-02
 33333  | receive   | 2013-07-03
 22222  | send      | 2013-07-03
 11111  | receive   | 2013-07-04
 55555  | send      | 2013-07-05
 22222  | receive   | 2013-07-06
 44444  | send      | 2013-07-07
 22222  | send      | 2013-07-07
 44444  | receive   | 2013-07-08
 55555  | receive   | 2013-07-09
 22222  | receive   | 2013-07-10
 33333  | send      | 2013-07-11
```

What I need to do is find each pairing of send-receives, where the receive is the first immediately following the send: 11111 is sent out on 7/2 and received on 7/4.  22222 is sent on 7/3 and then received on 7/6.  However, 22222 was also received on 7/2 and 7/10.

I initially tried using a join to itself to get some quick results:

```
SELECT a.ItemID, a.EventType, a.TransactionDate, b.EventType, b.TransactionDate, b.TransactionDate - a.TransactionDate AS "Days"
FROM Transactions a, Transactions b
WHERE a.ItemID = b.ItemID
AND a.EventType = 'send'
AND b.EventType = 'receive'
AND a.TransactionDate < b.TransactionDate
```

I knew this wouldn't get me the actual results I wanted, but it was a quick and dirty approximation.  The issue is that it will return multiple rows for the same send for every receive that comes after it (note the duplication of the first 22222 send transaction):

```
 a.ItemID | a.EventType | a.TransactionDate | b.EventType | b.TransactionDate | Days
----------|-------------|-------------------|-------------|-------------------|------
 11111    | send        | 2013-07-02        | receive     | 2013-07-04        | 2
 22222    | send        | 2013-07-03        | receive     | 2013-07-06        | 3
 22222    | send        | 2013-07-03        | receive     | 2013-07-10        | 7
 22222    | send        | 2013-07-07        | receive     | 2013-07-10        | 3
 44444    | send        | 2013-07-07        | receive     | 2013-07-08        | 1
 55555    | send        | 2013-07-05        | receive     | 2013-07-09        | 4
```

Google suggests I might use the LEAD analytic function.  This seems promising, but given I'm not familiar with it, I'm not sure how (or if) I can make it fit my model where the linking lines aren't directly paired (find the next transaction for 11111, regardless of type).  I'm hung up trying to limit the first transaction to sends, and the second to receives.  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

```
select t.*,
       lead(EventType) over (partition by ItemId order by TransactionDate) as NextEventType,
       lead(TransactionDate) over (partition by ItemId order by TransactionDate) as NextEventType,
from Transactions t
```

You can then calculate the days, but you need to use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (case when NextEventType = 'receive' then NextEventDate - EventDate end) as days
from (select t.*,
             lead(EventType) over (partition by ItemId order by TransactionDate) as NextEventType,
             lead(TransactionDate) over (partition by ItemId order by TransactionDate) as NextEventDate
      from Transactions t
     ) t
where t.EventType = 'send'
```

There are two challenges.  One is what happens if there are two sends in a row for the same item, but no receive. This will detect that situation and assign the receive to the second send.

The other is the timing.  If you have a send and receive for an event on the same date, there is no enough information to know which goes first.  This could pose a problem.  Your data does not have any such examples.  The solution is to include a time stamp, if this situation could occur.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I didn't think to use two LEAD statements, but it makes perfect sense now that I see how it works.